# web2py and python logging

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, web2py

I have web2py logging set up using logging.conf like this -

```
args=("logs/my_log.log", "a", 1000000, 5)
```

But I end up with many small files  like this -

```
    166 Aug  8 05:48 my_log.log.1
  34011 Aug  8 07:16 my_log.log.2
  28650 Aug  8 10:36 my_log.log.3
   9593 Aug  8 10:37 my_log.log.4
   3222 Aug  8 12:13 my_log.log
```

What could be the issue? I have a similar configuration for web2py scheduler. That creates only one file and keeps appending. I have only one scheduler job running. Is web2py creating 5 files in this specific case because there could be multiple sessions trying to write to one file, failing, and end up creating 5 files?

Comment: I assume it is a combination of 2 factors which led to this. First, the size(1000000)  was too small, The file switched.If file switch happens when we have concurrent sessions writing to the file, is it likely that they ended up creating separate files?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without looking at your web2y log configuration file / settings.

I've found it's easier to handle logs outside of web2py -- use generic settings, don't configure web2py to rotate / archive / delete logs, but use something like `logrotate` to manage all that.

Comment: That is OK. I have increased the size to 10000000000. Let me wait and watch.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar situation with multiple background web2py processes run with --import_models. The Scheduler runs background processes in a similar fashion. The standard logging.conf settings uses a RotatingFileHandler. This handler appears to check the size of the file descriptor that it has opened. When the size limit is exceeded, it opens a new file, and renames the current file.

The problem is that each background web2py process, including the scheduler processes, are looking at the log file they opened previously. So when one process detects the size limit has exceeded, that process moves on to a new log file. The other processes are still linked to the previous file. If a different process attempts to log something, it will see the size limit exceeded and move on to a new log file. Before long, each process will be writing to their own separate (small) log files.

My solution was to switch to the WatchedFileHandler and use logrotate to manage the log rotation. Prior to any logging event, the WatchedFileHandler will detect that its file has been rotated and (re)open the latest named log file. So all the processes will write to the latest named log file. Here is an excerpt of my web2py logging.conf settings:

```
[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,messageBoxHandler,watchedFileHandler
  :
[logger_<your web2py app>]
level=WARNING
qualname=web2py.app.<your web2py app>
handlers=consoleHandler,watchedFileHandler
propogate=0
  :
[handler_watchedFileHandler]
class=handlers.WatchedFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=("logs/web2py.log","a")
```

Here is my user space logrotate configuration

```
<path to logfile>/web2py.log {
    rotate 5
    maxsize 100000
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    nocreate
}
```